# Python regex split, integer of arbitrary length

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to do a simple regex split in Python. The string is in the form of FooX where Foo is some string and X is an arbitrary integer. I have a feeling this should be really simple, but I can't quite get it to work.

On that note, can anyone recommend some good Regex reading materials?

Comment: How do you want the split to be? Should it return only Foo? only the number? both?

Answer (score 6):

You can't use `split()` since that has to consume some characters, but you can use normal matching to do it.

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r'(\D+)(\d+)')
>>> r.match('abc444').groups()
('abc', '444')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using groups:

```
import re

m=re.match('^(?P<first>[A-Za-z]+)(?P<second>[0-9]+)$',"Foo9")
print m.group('first')
print m.group('second')
```

Using search:

```
import re

s='Foo9'
m=re.search('(?<=\D)(?=\d)',s)
first=s[:m.start()]
second=s[m.end():]

print first, second
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it simple:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "Foo1String12345"
>>> re.split(r'(\d+)$', a)[0:2]
['Foo1String', '12345']
```

Comment: simple... and allowing for digits in the "arbitrary string" :-p

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to split between the "Foo" and the number, you'd want something like:

```
r/(?<=\D)(?=\d)/
```

Which will match at a point between a nondigit and a digit, without consuming any characters in the split.

Comment: Great idea, but won't work, at least in Python. It ignores lookarounds in regexes that do not match any characters.

Comment: ...seriously? I wonder what the rationale for that behaviour is.

Comment: Hmm, it seems to ignore them for `split()` but it does work for `search()`. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> s="gnibbler1234"
>>> re.findall(r'(\D+)(\d+)',s)[0]
('gnibbler', '1234')
```

In the regex, \D means anything that is not a digit, so \D+ matches one or more things that are not digits.

Likewise \d means anything that is a digit, so \d+ matches one or more digits